# Spring boot @ResponBody entity null

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Tengo un problema hace unos días que todavía no puedo solucionar.

Tengo un método post de un *controller* que la entidad que esta relacionada llega null.

La entidad es empresa y esta relacionada con usuario en un `onetone`.
en el responbody empresa llega bien, pero usuario llega `null`

```
@Entity
@Table(name="EMPRESA")
public class Empresa  implements Serializable{
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="EMPRESA_ID")
    private Long empresaId;
    private String nombre;
    @Column(name="RAZON_SOCIAL")
    private String razonSocial;
    private String telefono;
    private String direccion;
    private String email;
    @Column(name="ESTADO_ID")
    private Long  estadoId;
    @Column(name="PRODUCTO_ID")
    private Long  productoId;
    @Column(name="FECHA_INICIALIZACION")
    private Date fechaInicializacion;
    
    @OneToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name="USUARIO_ID")
    private Usuario usuario;
}
```

##### Usuario

```
@Entity
@Table(name="USUARIO")
public class Usuario  implements Serializable {
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy =  GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="USUARIO_ID")
    private long usuarioId;
    private String usuario;
    private String password;
    @Column(name="FECHA_CREATE")
    private Date fechaCreacion;
    @Column(name="ESTADO_ID")
    private Long estadoId;
    @Column(name="ROL_USUARIO_ID")
    private Long rolUsuarioId;
    @Column(name="ROL_DESCRIPCION")
    private String descripcion;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="EMPRESA_ID")
    private Empresa sEmpresa;
    }
```

### Controller

```
@PostMapping(value="/empresa",consumes="application/json" ) 
     public ResponseEntity<?> save(@RequestBody Empresa xModel){
         Map<String, Object> response  = new HashMap<String, Object>();
         
         System.out.println(xModel.toString());
         try {
             empresaService.save(xModel);
             response.put("msg", "OK");         
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            response.put("msg", "KO");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return  new ResponseEntity<Map<String,Object>>(response, HttpStatus.OK);
         
     }
```

### objeto json que le envio desde el posman

```
{
"nombre": "javier",
"razonSocial":"pepe.sa",
"direccion":"Gorriti 411",
"telefono": "111221112",
"email":"zavhier@gmail.com",
"usuario":{
    "usuario":"zavhier",
    "password":"1232323"
}
}
```

debug
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

bueno si alguien me puede ayudar se los voy agradecer mucho.

Muy bueno comienzo de año. Salud

Answer (score 0):

el problema es que la clase Usuario necesita de un constructor vacío

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy =  GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="USUARIO_ID")
    private long usuarioId;
    private String usuario;
    private String password;
    @Column(name="FECHA_CREATE")
    private Date fechaCreacion;
    @Column(name="ESTADO_ID")
    private Long estadoId;
    @Column(name="ROL_USUARIO_ID")
    private Long rolUsuarioId;
    @Column(name="ROL_DESCRIPCION")
    private String descripcion;
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="EMPRESA_ID")
    private Empresa sEmpresa;
    

    public void Usuario(){}
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas gracias comunidad!

Comment: si quisieras mejorar tu respuesta vendria bien una liga a la especificacion javaBean de oracle :)